# I need to run NextJs application on AWS ec2 amazon linux in background

Tags: npm, next.js13, pm2, npx

I am using this command `npx serve@latest out`, "`out`" is the project folder name its run the project but when I logout from the terminal PuTTY it stops the application. I need to run the process in background.  What steps do I need to do?

I am also trying via pm2 and trying to create env-variable, but no success.

I'm trying to run a nextjs app.

Comment: You might want to expose env variables to browser you need to prefix it with NEXT_PUBLIC_+yourvariablename

Comment: Thanks for the input can you please more clarify NEXT_PUBLIC_+yourvariablename I mean next_public is the folder or enviroment variable ?

Comment: Its the variable name should be in uppercase like -
NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY